# How to add load more feature inside a dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, dropdown

**Bellow my simple html code for dropdown option**

```html
<select class="form-control" id="myList">
  <option  value="">Please select</option>  
  <option  value="1">1</option>
  <option  value="2">2</option>
  <option  value="3">3</option>
  <option  value="4">4</option>
  <option  value="5">5</option>
  <option  value="6">6</option>
  <option  value="7">7</option>
  <option  value="8">8</option>
  <option  value="9">9</option>
  <option value="load">
    <div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
  </option>
</select>
```

What i want to achive. I will show the option 1-5 after when click loadmore then will show more 5. I have researched few resource those are too poor and not so clear instruction. If you guys help me about it i will be glad for that. Thanks to all seniours developers.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: This is a poor UX decision. Dropdown lists don't normally work that way and changing yours to do that would be out of the ordinary for users who don't take the time to read all the options. Also [`option` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) can't contain other HTML. You should consider using the `size` attribute on the `select` to change it from a dropdown list to a scrollable list of a certain size.

Comment: *"Thanks to all seniours developers."* I'm a seniours  developer, but more importantly I'm a ***serious*** developer. Please include the JavaScript/jQuery that is too poor as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Use this function on onClick on loadMore id

```
function addMore() {
    var optionsArr = ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20']
    for (let i = 0; i < optionsArr.length; i++) {
        var options = `<option value="${optionsArr[i]}">${optionsArr[i]}</option>`
        $("#myList").append(options)
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you